# Set width of element based on content within

Tags: html, css, width, zurb-foundation

I have created a gradient line separator for cells in a grid. I would like to set the width based on the length of the heading. So, for the attached picture, I would like the line to only go to the end of the work "Filmmaking" instead of to the edge of the container.

One cell of the grid:
[image]

```
<div class="h3">Title</div>
<div class="gradient-line"></div>
<p>Description</p>
```

```
.gradient-line {
    height: 7px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #007476, #007182, #006e8c, #1e6892, #3f6293, #615f92, #7b5d8c, #8f5b81, #a46376, #af716c, #b28168, #ae936c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contain both title and gradient line div in to a separate parent div, from there set the width for the parent div with fit-content

HTML

```
<div class="fit">
  <div class="h3"> Title </div>
  <div class="gradient-line"></div>
</div>
<p>Description</p>
```

CSS

```
.fit { width: fit-content; }
.gradient-line {
     height: 7px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #007476, #007182, #006e8c, #1e6892, #3f6293, #615f92, #7b5d8c, #8f5b81, #a46376, #af716c, #b28168, #ae936c);
}
```

Comment: This does not work since the width of the h3 fits its parent container still

Answer (score 0):

As the gradient is purely for decoration, not really part of the actual content, you could put it as the background image to the h3 element and remove the div that holds it.

Obviously you'll want to set the padding on the heading as you require.

```css
.h3 {
  width: fit-content;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #007476, #007182, #006e8c, #1e6892, #3f6293, #615f92, #7b5d8c, #8f5b81, #a46376, #af716c, #b28168, #ae936c);
  background-position: left bottom;
  background-size: auto 7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="h3">Title</div>
<p>Description</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for one-line titles, but since I have these contained in a grid, each of the elements are set to 25% of the width of the page. The h3s with longer titles take up two lines, so their content boxes fill the whole container width rather than just to the length of the words. Is there a way to make the h3 container fit to only how much space the words take up and no more?

Comment: OK, so you need the width of the 'underline' to be equal to the width of the text in the longest line, not the width of the element. I just copied your snippet which is a short one-liner without thinking about the bigger problem, sorry. Will ponder.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I can't see how to do this without some Javascript. Is adding some JS acceptable?